# How to deploy Nuxt SSR app to firebase through cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I followed this [medium post](https://medium.com/likecoin/quick-nuxt-js-ssr-prototyping-with-firebase-cloud-functions-5277553610a8) as a guide to host my nuxt app on firebase hosting.

The deploy goes through, however, when I then visit the [url](https://helpacafe.firebaseapp.com) I get a `Cannot GET /` error message. If I check the function logs I see that the function completes with a 404 error.

This is my *functions/index.js*

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt-start')
const nuxtConfig = require('./nuxt.config.js')

admin.initializeApp()

const config = {
  ...nuxtConfig,
  dev: false,
  debug: true,
  buildDir: "nuxt",
  publicPath: "public",
}

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

exports.ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  await nuxt.ready()
  nuxt.render(req, res)
})
```

And this is the firebase configuration

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix src run build && rm -rf functions/nuxt && cp -r src/nuxt/ functions/nuxt/ && cp src/nuxt.config.js functions/"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "predeploy": [
      "rm -rf public/* && mkdir -p public/_nuxt && cp -a src/nuxt/dist/client/. public/_nuxt && cp -a src/static/. public/ && cp -a public_base/. public/"
    ],
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrapp"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The project structure is this

```
/
 /src
 /functions
 /public
 /public_base
```

When I run `firebase deploy` I do see the content of /src being copied to /functions/nuxt. For the sake of testing I also have my */functions/package.json* file include all the dependencies that I have in my */src/package.json* file.

How can I get this app up and running? If you need any more details, let me know.

#### Update #1

I tried serving hosting and functions using the command `firebase serve --only functions,hosting -p 5004`.

Running the server like so gave me some more insights. Specifically I got this warning message at load time that then resulted in actual error message when loading the page.

```
WARN  Module @firebase/app not found. Silently ignoring module as programatic usage detected
```

I didn't install this package in the functions directory as I did not have it in my src directory either. However, after installing it inside /functions and restarting the dev server, that warning message was gone and with it also the error I was getting on page load.

I also spotted a couple of warnings that had to do with vue, vue-server-renderer and vue-template-compiler not running the same version.

Now everything seems to be working fine!

Answer (score 3):

Your config and structure look right.

I also did this about a year ago with my app and I ran into the same problem. It has to do with the function code itself. I also tried using `nuxt.render(req, res)` ([Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt-render)) but it never worked for me so I ended up using `nuxt.renderRoute(route)` ([Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt-render-route)) instead. This worked perfectly fine.

You could change your code to something like this:

```
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt')

...

exports.ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  await nuxt.ready()

  const result = await nuxt.renderRoute(req.path) // Returns { html, error, redirected }
  res.send(result.html) // Sends html as response
})
```

This worked for me. You should consider catching any errors though. I hope this solves your problem.

*This is only a work-around, if anyone knows why `nuxt.render` isn't working, I would be interested to know. I wasted many hours because of this with my app...*

Comment: Thanks Florian! Will test this later this morning and let you know

Comment: Hey Florian. At first I was loading nuxt using the nuxt-start package. However, when calling nuxt.renderRoute I got an error saying that renderRoute was not a function. By reading the docs i can see that instead of using nuxt-start, they are using loadNuxt from the nuxt package. Now, however, I get a Cannot find the firebase namespace error. How did you create the nuxt instance in your app?

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that. I use the regular nuxt package for import. I'm not familiar with the nuxt-start package, though.
`const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt')`

Answer (score 2):

I tried serving hosting and functions locally using the command `firebase serve --only functions,hosting -p 5004`.

By doing this I was able to spot a bunch of warnings and errors such as

```
FATAL 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.5.21
- vue-server-renderer@2.6.11

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.

WARN  Module @firebase/app not found. Silently ignoring module as programatic usage detected
```

I then made sure that those vue packages were indeed running the same version. Then I also added the `@firebase/app` package in `/functions/package.json` (that however, is not present in `/src/package.json`.

I run the local server again and everything worked. I then deployed to firebase and everything was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

the following works for me (using nuxt-start instead):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { Nuxt } = require("nuxt-start");

const config = {
  dev: false
};

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

let isReady = false;

async function handleRequest(req, res) {
  if (!isReady) {
    try {
      isReady = await nuxt.ready();
    } catch (error) {
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
  await nuxt.render(req, res);
}

exports.nuxtssr = functions.https.onRequest(handleRequest);
```